# Efficient stats from Access DB

Tags: vb.net

I am pulling stats from Access DB and using the following:

```
'''
    countBP = Convert.ToInt32(New OleDbCommand(commandBP.ToString, con).ExecuteScalar)
    countWP = Convert.ToInt32(New OleDbCommand(commandWP.ToString, con).ExecuteScalar)
    countHP = Convert.ToInt32(New OleDbCommand(commandHP.ToString, con).ExecuteScalar)
'''
```

where:

```
'''
    command = ""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees WHERE Archived = 'N' AND ID > 2"
    commandBP = command.ToString + " AND Ethnic = 'B' AND EmployeeType = 1"
    commandWP = command.ToString + " AND Ethnic = 'W' AND EmployeeType = 1"
    commandHP = command.ToString + " AND Ethnic = 'H' AND EmployeeType = 1"
'''
```

My question is; is this efficient? I am pulling 20+ stats separately, and it seems to be taking more and more time to load as the DB grows. I wondering if "SELECT * FROM Employees" to a dataset and then filter would be a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only variable part of your query is the Ethnic field. This suggest to use the [Group By](https://documentation.help/MS-Jet-SQL/dasqlgroupby.htm) clause on that field

```
command = "SELECT Ethnic, COUNT(*) FROM Employees 
           WHERE Archived = 'N' AND ID > 2 AND EmployeeType = 1
           GROUP BY Ethnic"
```

Now this reduces the database calls to just one call and you can retrieve your data with

```
Dim data as Dictionary(Of String, Int32) = new Dictionary(Of String, Int32)()
OleDbCommand cmd = New OleDbCommand(command, con)
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
    data(reader.GetString(0)) = reader.GetInt32(1)
End While
```

At this point you can get the count values from your dictionary

```
Dim countBP as Integer
data.TryGetValue("B", countBP) 
....
```

Notice that you should use the TryGetValue method to extract values from the database because if there are no record for Ethnic = "B" there will be no entry in the dictionary for the Key "B" but TryGetValue will leave the CountBP initialized with its default to zero.

Comment: Nice clean example of Group By.